# Converting to Roman Numeral with Recursive Algorithm

Tags: programming-challenge, converting, vba, vb6, roman-numerals

## Summary

I'm getting ready to dive back into a "more proper" project, so I wanted to take a moment to get my TDD hat on before doing so. I decided to tackle this [Roman Numeral Kata](http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/index.pl?KataRomanNumerals) for practice. The purpose of the function is simply to take in a `Long` and output a string containing the equivalent Roman Numeral.

I'm confident that it's accurate out to 3999. [Beyond that a standard keyboard doesn't quite have the proper characters,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers) so 4000 comes out as `MMMM` and 14841 comes out as `MMMMMMMMMMMMMMDCCCXLI`. [Unit Tests can be found in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ckuhn203/bc2399a38ac171e1ab0d) if you're interested.

I didn't *plan* on doing this recursively. It just kind of came out naturally after a few refactorings. I did at one point extract a few functions to reduce the redundancy in the code below, but it ***really*** felt like it obfuscated the algorithm and hurt the clarity.

## Questions

- Was the recursive solution a good way to go? I feel like it's clear, but I have this nagging feeling there might be a better algorithm. (One that may involve determining decimal places perhaps?)
- Is it dry enough as it is, or *should* I have extracted a few functions like this.

  ```
  Private Function UpFrom(ByVal number As Long, ByVal from As Long) As String
      UpFrom = ConvertToRomanNumeral(from) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - from)
  End Function
  ```
- Should I have raised an error after reaching 4000, instead of returning "numeral like" strings?
- Did I do anything else stupid or dirty? Anything you'd do differently?

## Numbers.bas

```
Public Function ConvertToRomanNumeral(ByVal number As Long) As String
    Dim result As String

    Select Case number
        Case 1
            result = "I"
        Case 2 To 3
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 1) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(1)
        Case 4
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(1) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(5)
        Case 5
            result = "V"
        Case 6 To 8
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(5) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 5)
        Case 9
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(1) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(10)
        Case 10
            result = "X"
        Case 11 To 39
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(10) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 10)
        Case 40
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(10) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(50)
        Case 41 To 49
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(40) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 40)
        Case 50
            result = "L"
        Case 51 To 89
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(50) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 50)
        Case 90
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(10) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(100)
        Case 91 To 99
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(90) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 90)
        Case 100
            result = "C"
        Case 101 To 399
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(100) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 100)
        Case 400
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(100) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(500)
        Case 401 To 499
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(400) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 400)
        Case 500
            result = "D"
        Case 501 To 899
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(500) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 500)
        Case 900
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(100) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(1000)
        Case 901 To 999
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(900) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 900)
        Case 1000
            result = "M"
        Case Else
            result = ConvertToRomanNumeral(1000) & ConvertToRomanNumeral(number - 1000)
    End Select

    ConvertToRomanNumeral = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Not to be *negative*, but...

Your `Else` case is making a bad assumption, that whichever number reaches that branch is going to be greater than 1000. I don't mind the recursion; I don't even mind the `Select Case` - but by not handling negative integers you have a bug there, where -42 is going to be treated as if it were greater than 1000, and even worse, it's going to be subtracted 1000 before being fed into a recursive call: I haven't executed it, but it seems your code would blow up with a very easily avoidable *overflow* error with just about any negative input.

There should be an input validation guard clause before the select block, to ensure you're not entering a recursive logic with a zero or negative input.

Now if valid input is an integer between 1 and 3999, then there is no need to intake a `Long` - the `Integer` data type is sufficient.

Comment: Yup. I think that qualifies as "something stupid". Thanks. =)

Comment: adding `Case < 1` at the start, and `Case > 3999` just before the case else should help with boundaries